# Seismograph Chart in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I am creating a seismic recording app in IOS. I want to show seismograph chart in my app like [image: this]. I have searched a lot on google and github but unable to find EXACTLY same visual. I am currently using "Charts" library from github but it is not producing same visual effect. Please suggest me just name of library.

Comment: https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts
Check the example on GitHub home page. Resembles quite a bit.

Comment: I have seen that library already, It is not exactly same. Values in graph are based from bottom on the other hand I need library in which values depend on center axis.

Comment: Chart libraries are limited in iOS. You need to apply customisations with the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks Nitish, I seems to be only option.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources like libraries is considered off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Joakim Danielson, can you help me in creating this?

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the Help section to understan what kind of questions you can ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use LineChartView of [this](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) {https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts} library. By default your view will not resemble to seismograph but you need to customise it. To do this, whenever you add a point to graph, also add the point of same value but negative value. For example you want to show an earth-quake of magnitude 5. You should add a point of value 5. At the same time also add a point of value -5. This will give view like seismograph. If you can’t understand then reply, I will provide you code for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

What about this https://github.com/vegather/GraphView ?
It will not compile unless you build against a device (even a generic one) because it uses metal.